# Is it possible to have bit fields array?

Tags: c, bit-fields

I have an unsigned char array of size 256:

```
unsigned char test[256];
```

I want to reduce the size of the array such that there is only one bit consumed by each index, for example index 0 to 7 should consume 1 byte so i only need 256/8 bytes. Is it possible to do that in C?

Comment: It is not possible with C syntax. You can implement it with functions.

Comment: Scarlet, No.  Instead use `unsigned char test[256/8];` and mask operations.

Comment: Why can't op use struct with 256 1-bit fields?

Comment: @AllanWind You could have 256 1-bit fields, but you couldn't access them using array syntax. Each bitfield would be individually named.

Comment: Even compilers that support bit-sized data types as an extension don't allow arrays of bits, at least the ones I used.

Comment: A footnote to §6.7.2.1 in the C11 Standard says: *The unary & (address-of) operator cannot be applied to a bit-field object; thus, there are no pointers to
or arrays of bit-field objects.*

Comment: You would have to define your own functions to get, set, test (etc.) the appropriate bits of a 256/8 array. But the code for those functions would almost certainly take up more memory than the 224 bytes you would save.

Comment: The C++ Standards committee tried something like this over 10 years ago when specifying how a `std::vector` of `bool` should work. The complaints *still* haven't stopped.